# new Uri decoding relative path

Tags: c#, .net, url-encoding

The following code...

```
string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
Console.WriteLine(date);
string encodedDate = WebUtility.UrlEncode(date);
Console.WriteLine(encodedDate);
Uri uri = new Uri("https://mywebsite/");
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
string relativePath = $"/mM0jpk613J5lzY00c3EaxQ%3D%3D/{encodedDate}";
Console.WriteLine(relativePath);
uri = new Uri(uri, relativePath);
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
```

Produces the following output is:-

```
2016-03-07T08:17:38.5247330Z
2016-03-07T08%3A17%3A38.5247330Z
https://mywebsite/
/mM0jpk613J5lzY00c3EaxQ%3D%3D/2016-03-07T08%3A17%3A38.5247330Z
https://mywebsite/mM0jpk613J5lzY00c3EaxQ%3D%3D/2016-03-07T08:17:38.5247330Z
```

I was expecting the last line to be

> https://mywebsite/mM0jpk613J5lzY00c3EaxQ%3D%3D/2016-03-07T08%3A17%3A38.5247330Z

Why does Uri unescape the relative path?  A work around seems to be to encode the relativepath twice, but why?

Is there an alternative method I should be using to create this url?

EDIT: I updated the code to display even more odd behavior, the first part of the relative uri remains encoded, but the second does not!

Comment: I've logged this as a bug at microsoft connect...

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2444172

Comment: Lets do the math on if this is a bug. How many developers use the Uri class every day? Lots I think! Uri has been in .net since version 1.1 - 2003 ish? I think they would have noticed by now...

Comment: @Gusdor I'm well aware of how long Uri has been in the framework.  I would say from the first beta 2001 (which I used).  Never the less if you run the code it does not behave consistently, what possible logical explanation can there be for it decoding one half of the relative path and leave the other half encoded?

Comment: In anyone is wondering my work around was to use a file time instead which doesn't require encoding and decoding

Answer (score 2):

URI is an object and will represent the link in its clean/unescaped form. If you are looking for retrieving it the way it was added, use the below property.

```
uri.OriginalString
```

Comment: Yea I'm still not understanding the logic, what is the use of an unescaped URI?  I think your answer seemed more acceptable before my edit.  This seems like a bug to me.  Do you agree?

Comment: Not really a bug, but agree that it would have been useful to have an uri.EscapedString property available.

Comment: How do you explain part of the relativePath string being decoded and the other part not?

Comment: After the edit, yes, it is evident whatever "clean up" was attempted is applied only to last part of relative URL. Looks strange, must be a bug.

Comment: @Mick The string is unescaped when you add it. This is so the api can ensure consistency across all strings. It is less likely that the developer will escape the uri strings in the source code, than just use plain text. In fact, I think it pretty mad to do so. This method will escape the final uri string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx The uri encoding is a protocol problem and is handled individually by the APIs that consume URIs.